# Use Select instead of Include

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

so I have this big table that I want to query and it's so slow, I got a tip that using select is more efficient than include. so how can I convert include to select, in this big query.

```
    ProductEntity? i = await _context.Set<ProductEntity>()
        .Include(i => i.Media)
        .Include(i => i.Categories)
        .Include(i => i.Locations)
        .Include(i => i.Reports)
        .Include(i => i.Comments)!.ThenInclude(x => x.LikeComments)
        .Include(i => i.Bookmarks)
        .Include(i => i.Votes)
        .Include(i => i.User)!.ThenInclude(x => x.Media)
        .Include(i => i.User)!.ThenInclude(x => x.Categories)
        .Include(i => i.Forms)!.ThenInclude(x => x.FormField)
        .Include(i => i.Teams)!.ThenInclude(x => x.User)!.ThenInclude(x => x.Media)
        .Include(i => i.VoteFields)!.ThenInclude(x => x.Votes)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id && i.DeletedAt == null);
    return new GenericResponse<ProductEntity>(_mapper.Map<ProductEntity>(i));
```

and this is getById method, which just takes one row, I have a getAll that returns a list of products just like this.

Comment: Have you checked if the resulting query is slow on the server? You might need to look at indexes

Comment: Use `AsSplitQuery()`

Comment: Yes, a projection is more efficient than including "everything", but we have no clue of what info you need or where to get it from.

Answer (score 0):

The most performant code is always the code that does the least amount of work.

It's possible that what was meant by the 'tip' that "using select is more efficient" may have more to do with answering the question: "do you really, really, really need all that data to be returned?".

Consider, for every `.Include` you have, EF will be making it's own query to the database to return whatever records are linked by the foreign keys. It's actually pretty efficient on doing that either on the DB side, or in memory if it already has the connected records in memory. (depending on your caching configuration) However, it's going to return the entire Entity referenced. Which may be fine. But, what if each of those 11 sub-entities plus the 7 sub-sub-entities that you have connecting there are each rather large. Do you really, really, really need to return all of that data? Or could you return smaller objects using something like:

```cs
var mySmallerObject = await _context.Set<ProductEntity>()
    .Include(i => i.Media)
    .Include(i => i.Categories)
    . . .
    .Select(_ => new SomeMuchSmallerObject {
        SomeFieldOnProduct = _.SomeFieldOnProduct, 
        TheOnlyThingINeedFromMedia = _.Media.TheOnlyThingINeedFromMedia,
        TheOnlyCategoryFieldINeed = _.Categories.TheOnlyCategoryFieldINeed,
        . . . // etc
    })
```

UPDATED
Note: You will still need to either keep all those `.Include()`s to let EF implicitly build the joins, or else convert them to explicit `.Join()` statements. By making a smaller object that you use in the `.Select()` statement, EF will translate *this* request into a much more optimized query to the DB that only selects the few fields you actually need, and not even return any of the unwanted fields from the database. This also allows you to take full advantage of any indexes you have on the underlying tables in the DB.

Just a thought.

Comment: Actually you don't need includes when doing a `.Select()` query like that. The query for the fields requested will be done in SQL without bringing entire object graphs into memory.

Comment: @Valuator, if you don't include the `.Include` then OP would need to introduce `.Join` to get to the fields on those other tables. But leaving the `.Include` there like that lets EF build those joins in SQL implicitly. As long as they are not included in the `.Select` then they wont even be returned from the DB, so there's no harm in actually leaving them there.